# Jquery Body change event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How to capture the body change event in the attached image source?

Basically i want to set max characters to ajaxcontrol html editor without using any other third party control.

[image]

I have tried the following script, but no luck.

```
$('body', $('iframe#MainContent_VWIContent_AdminContent_ManageLoginPageMsgControl_txtHtmlMessage_ctl02_ctl00').contents()).on('keyup', function (e) {
    alert('testing');
});
```

Comment: see some errors in console?

Comment: @Cherniv No, I dont see any error or warning.

Comment: is it finds this iframe at all? check if this shows 1: `$('iframe#MainContent_VWIContent_AdminContent_ManageLoginPageMsgControl_txtHtmlMessage_ctl02_ctl00').length`

Comment: Are you checking for textbox keyup event of element in iFrame?

Comment: @Cherniv, it returns 0 even if there is some text.

Comment: @Nil, its not a textbox. I'm using Ajax control toolkit HTMLEditor.

Comment: it means that iframe with this id not found. may be it is iframe inside iframe?